# Does Appium need Xcode for run automated testing on iOS device?

Tags: ios, xcode, appium

I'm trying to run automated testing on iOS devices without installing Xcode, but seem like it doesn't work.

So I just want to know that Does Appium really need Xcode for run automated testing on iOS device? and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode needs to be present for Appium to work.

Appium's command life-cycle, works as :

Selenium webdriver picks a command form the code like (Element.click) and sends it in form of JSON via http request to the Appium server. Appium server knows the automation context like the iOS and Android and sends this command to the Instruments command server which will wait for the Instruments command client (written in node.js) to pick it up and execute it in bootstrap.js with in the iOS instruments environment. Once the command is executed the command client sends back the message to the Appium server which logs everything related to the command in its console. This cycle keeps going till the time all the commands gets executed.

Apple’s instruments binary, which Appium uses to launch the iOS simulator, by default uses the currently-selected Xcode, and the highest iOS SDK installed with that version of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

Appium uses the [appium-xcuitest-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver) to test iOS devices using the Xcode UI Testing protocol. Under the hood, it will launch the [WebDriverAgent](https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent) on the iOS device, which does the heavy lifting.

There is 3rd party, commercial software which allow you to launch Appium tests on iOS devices without having to use Xcode. Such examples are Mobile Center from MicroFocus, Appium Studio from Experitest, or [the quamotion/appion-docker-ios](https://github.com/quamotion/appium-docker-ios) docker image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need xcode to run you test on ios. And yes it supports native, hybrid as well as browsers.